# How do you return a formatted string in C?

Tags: c, string

So basically I have a function that calculates three integer values: day, month, year

I want it to return a string in format "day/month/year"

This is the function:

```
char* generateDate(int day, int month, int year){ 
  day++;
  int dayCount = 31;
  if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
    dayCount = 30;
  } 
  else if (month == 2) {
    dayCount = 28;
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
      dayCount = 29;
      if (year % 100 == 0) {
        dayCount = 28;
        if (year % 400 == 0) {
          dayCount = 29;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (day > dayCount) {
    day = 1;
    month++;
    if (month > 12) {
      month = 1;
      year++;
    }
  }

  char* date = malloc(10);
  char* s_day;
  sprintf(s_day, "%f", day);
  date[0] = day;
  return date;
}
```

Near the bottom of the function, I create a pointer to a char array, and try to convert day (which is an int) to a string and add it to the array but that doesn't work yet. I get the following error:

```
RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,819, total time: 1s)
```

I realize that converting int to string doesn't work as easily as I think, especially to then only add it to to an array.

**I basically want to take:  int day, int month, int year and return:
"day/month/year"    (does not need to be a pointer, unless necessary. It can be passed by value to calling code)**

Sorry if it's a silly error, I'm very used to Java and C# where working with strings is so easy

Comment: `s_day` not initialized to point to a properly allocated block of memory.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `date[0] = day`, when `date` is an array of characters and `day` is an integer?

Comment: Why are you setting `date` to point to an allocated block of memory of 10 bytes?

Comment: You are not doing anything with `s_day`, so what's the purpose of this local variable in the function?

Comment: Why are you specifying `%f` for `day` of type `int`?

Comment: If you just eant to return a string with the full date what are all those calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to return an allocated string with the full date, your task is quite trivial. You just need to build the string with a function like `sprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* generateDate(int day, int month, int year)
{ 
    /* here you should place parameters check */

    char retString = malloc( 11 );

    sprintf (retString, "%02d/%02d/%04d", day, month, year);

    return retString;
 }
```

Please note how format `%02d` prints a 2 digits integer with a leading 0 in case the corresponding integer is only one digit long.

We allocate 11 chars because:

- 2 are for the day
- 2 are for the month
- 4 are for the year
- 2 are for the separators `'/'`
- 1 is required for **the string terminator**

Of course the function can be improved by inserting parameters check at the beginning of the function, and returning `NULL` if they are wrong.

1. Make sure that `year` is lower than 9999 (for sanity)
2. Make sure that `month` is between 1 and 12
3. With a `switch-case` conditional, set a variable `dayMax` to the maximum number of days of every month, and check `day` so that it is icluded between 1 and `dayMax`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly it looks like you want to calculate the date of the next day.

One way to do that without having to calculate all that you are doing is to use the built-in runtime functions in C

```
struct tm myDate = {0, 0, 0,day,month-1,year - 1900,0,0,-1};
time_t seconds = mktime(&myDate); // strictly speaking it is clock ticks but secs normally
seconds += 3600*24; // add a day of seconds
localtime_s(&myDate, &seconds);
```

now you have year, month and day for next day and don't have think about leap year etc.

to return this string to caller either pass a buffer to the function or allocate some memory

```
char* s_day = malloc( 4 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 ); // 0000/00/00 + \0
sprintf_s( s_day, "%d/%d/%d", myDate.tm_mday, myDate.tm_mon + 1, myDate.tm_year + 1900);
return s_day;
```

EDIT: If you prefer to have the format with leading zeros use the format string

```
"%02d/%02d/%d" instead
```